# Spring dependency Error

Tags: ajax, spring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I got an error:

> ("cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'dependency'. One of
>   '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http:// 
>   www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean,
>   WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"]}' is
>   expected.)

i have been included (jackson-mapper-asl and jackson-core-asl) into my lib in my Work Space
not getting Why This Error Occurred Kindly Help.

Answer (score 2):

You have two things mixed up: Spring Configuration files and Maven's project configuration file (pom.xml). The `<dependency>` element belongs in the pom.xml file, not in the Spring Configuration.

Also you do not need to include the jar files anywhere, Maven takes care of the dependencies.